# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 ASP.NET Core project wont load

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I recently update Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and ASP.NET tooling Preview 2. Then when I open old ASP.NET Core RC2 project it fails with message

D:\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.xproj : error  : Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory+ProjectLoadHelper" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.

Than I try to create new ASP.NET project from scratch but with same error.

Does anybody know what error means?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came across a very similar problem.

The procedure described here worked well for me:

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1455#issuecomment-229146688

Comment: Unfortunately not for me. I try all procedures but without success.